# RecyclerView doesn't work well with Handler

Tags: android

I use Handlers to update RecyclerView items asynchronously, but it seems like my view doesn't (only) update the correct items.

**My code:**

```
mHandler.post(new Runnable() {
    @Override
        public void run() {
            // palette and image stuff
            // ...

            runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                // shortcut for loading images and update view holder which 
                // works as it was intended but only when not started 
                //from Handler
                load(...) 
            });    
        }
});
```

**Behavior:**

As I start scrolling down in my list, I can clearly see as the RecyclerView loads **every** single **item to every view**. Something like this:

View 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6... get loaded.
I scroll down to the (e.g) 20th items. And View #20 loads (into itself) the layout of View #7, #8, 9, 10, 11, 12, ... until 20, but all of the unnecessary views are visible only for a few ms. After that it stops changing layouts at the corresponding view.

**Help:**

Have you seen similar to that? Why does that happen and what shall I do?

Comment: The question is not very clear. Share more code if necessary.

Comment: This is the guilty code. If I setup all my views synchronously then everything works fine, but it's painfully slow. Hence, I call the code (above) in every onBindViewHolder call. Then inside the **load** method, I set textview text, imageview source etc...